# Dictionary assignment in python or strange abstraction

Tags: python

I'm reading a book on data structures and algorithms and understand the overall goal of the code but for top() and pop() there are strange member variables. Is this some sort of python abstraction that I am running into (ex. self._head._element) or a feature of not using pythons dictionary variable assignment? 
'''

```
class LinkedStack:
    class _Node:
        __slots__ = '_element','_next' #treats elements not like a dictionary

        def __init__(self, element, next):
            self._element = element
            self._next = next

def __init__(self):
    self._head = None
    self._size = 0

def __len__(self):
    return self._size

def is_empty(self):
    return self._size == 0

def push(self, e):
    self._head = self._Node(e, self._head)
    self._size += 1

def top(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Empty('Stack is empty')
    else:
        return self._head._element  

def pop(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Empty('Stack is empty')
    answer = self._head._element
    self._head = self._head._next
    self._size -=1
    return answer
```

'''

Comment: What is strange? The only thing strange here is the nested class? Do you mean the leading single underscores in the names? What do you mean by "using pythons dictionary variable assignment?"

Comment: They (`_head`, and `_element`) are simply attribute names, there is nothing special with them. You may have been confused by the fact that `_head` is a `_Node` instance itself.

Comment: the problem is that its accessing two members at once? Its not like in C/C++ where you access the member variable through another class. In this case its like it is a member variable being used to access another member variable

Comment: Also the underscore is the books way of differentiating variables that can only be accessed through an object